# Ansbile + AWS Private hosts provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, provisioning

I am trying to provision 2 ec2 instances on a private subnet using Ansible playbooks. My infrastructure includes:

- Bastion Host on a public subnet
- 2 EC2 instances on 2 private subnets
- NAT Gate for outgoing connections
- Application Load Balancer

My question is how to run the Ansible playbook from localhost to affect the private instances. Can I SSH forward the playbook or does the playbook have to reside in the bastion host and then use the private IPs as hosts?

Answer (score 3):

Create [ssh-config](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/) file `~/.ssh/config` and then add the following line to config file

```
host bastion
   HostName bastion_ip
   User bastion_user
   identityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem

host private_instance
   HostName  10.0.0.11
   user  private_ec2_user
   ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
   identityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

> My question is how to run the Ansible playbook from localhost to
>   affect the private instances.

Now you have configured `ssh config` file all you need to type

```
ssh private_instance
```

this will create SSH tunneling to your private instance, you do not need complex or lengthy command to type every time.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible allows the use of SSH configuration options and ProxyCommand can come to rescue when trying to forward the command from bastion to private subnet hosts. Here is an example

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh ubuntu@52.50.10.5 'nc 192.168.0.20 22'" ubuntu@nothing
```

The above command will, for example, first connect to 52.50.10.5 via SSH, and then open a socket to 192.168.0.20 on port 22. The socket connection (which is connected to the remote SSH server) is then passed to the original SSH client command invocation to utilize.

Source : https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/16/ansible-aws-ec2-vpc/